# Problem installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 on ASUS X551MA-SX153D

Tags: asus

I bought an ASUS X551MA-SX153D laptop and I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 via a USB flash dive. However, I got this error:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
drm_kms_helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

The laptop is completely new and it did not come with a pre-installed version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend checking the MD5 hash [here on the Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) to see if the ISO has been corrupted during the download

Second it can also depend on the software used to put the installer onto, personally I've used [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) with the best results (If I don't know the software, it makes it a bit harder to research)

There may also be something to do with the BIOS settings, if you go into your BIOS settings there might be an option for a boot mode (Normally Windows 8 or Windows 7/other are the options) which should be set to Windows7/other to boot Ubuntu